# I'm trying to control a drum kit sequencer with a dropdown menu in Javascript but having some problems

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a drop down menu which decides which type of drum kit to select on a drum sequencer using 'select' and 'option' in HTML. I then have a variable called kitNumber which is initially set to 0 (first kit). I then have a function to control it in Javascript as you can see in my code.

I know that I need to replace the initial 0 with my function but when I do this, the code doesn't work. Apologies if I'm not explaining myself that well but I'll put my code in this post so I hope this helps to solve the problem. Any help on this is much appreciated, thank you.

```js
var kitNumber = 0; // select the kit and load it

var drumKitSelect = document.getElementById("drumKitSelect");
drumKitSelect.addEventListener("input", drumKitActions);

  function drumKitActions() {
   if (drumKitSelect.value == 0) {
    kitNumber = 0;
    console.log("value 1 selected");
   }
   else if (drumKitSelect.value == 1) {
    kitNumber = 1;
    console.log("value 2 selected");
   }
   else if (drumKitSelect.value == 2) {
    kitNumber = 2;
    console.log("value 3 selected");
   }
   else if (drumKitSelect.value == 3) {
    kitNumber = 3;
    console.log("value 4 selected");
   }
  }
```

```html
<select id="drumKitSelect">
  <option value="0">Hip Hop</option>
  <option value="1">House</option>
  <option value="2">Garage</option>
  <option value="3">Drum & Bass</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: For simplifying your code, you might want to use a "switch" statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem.  The snippet provided sets the kitNumber var and console.log's a message in each case.  Could you further explain your issue?

Comment: how would i go about doing this in my code?

Comment: the code doesn't change the kitNumber, it just stays at 0, whichever option i select

Comment: is this code happening one time at the document.ready?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error; I am assuming that your issue is related to something not provided in your snippet.

Comment: Evya2005 - not sure what you mean

Comment: dav - ahh it must be, im not sure what though.. ill have to have a look through and see if ive done something else wrong

Comment: Btw, this is what I meant by using a switch statement: https://jsfiddle.net/hdv97ast/ However, given the simplicity of your current code, it could be far more simplified by doing something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hdv97ast/1/

Comment: cheers mate, will check that out and try to implement it in my code!

Comment: i think what the problem is, is that the sequencer isn't setting itself to the desired kitNumber when selected, as when i change the kitNumber in the console, the kit doesn't change. so i'll need to figure out how to make the sequencer constantly reset itself